# Getting Invalid header signature Exception while reading word document from file system in java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to read a word document (.doc) which has been exported from confluence page in my org using the below code, I am getting the following exception, Am I doing anything wrong initializing word doc like this. If I read a word doc that I have created I am not getting any exception.

```
try {
                POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
                HWPFDocument document = new HWPFDocument(fs);
```

```
org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NotOLE2FileException: Invalid header signature; read 0x7265562D454D494D, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:149)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:115)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.<init>(POIFSFileSystem.java:326)
```

Comment: "Invalid header signature; read 0x7265562D454D494D": If the file starts with these bytes, then it is not a valid OLE2 document. The bytes are ASCII code: "MIME-Ver" read in Little-Endian-Format. So the file seems to start with the text "MIME-Version". That looks like a header field content instead of the start of a file. How was the file stored?

Comment: I have saved the file into my file system by exporting it from the atlassian confluence article in the browser from the option export to word

Comment: When i opened the saved document in vs code i am seeing the following text - ----- MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="----=_NextPart_01D9BBC8.A1782840"

This document is a Single File Web Page, also known as a Web Archive file.  If you are seeing this message, your browser or editor doesn't support Web Archive files.  Please download a browser that supports Web Archive.

------=_NextPart_01D9BBC8.A1782840

Comment: "If you are seeing this message, your browser or editor doesn't support Web Archive files." This message is very clear. Apache POI doesn't support Web Archive files.

Comment: One update on the issue is i opened the exported word document from confluence in ms word and saved it back as .doc then my word doc parser written using apache poi is able to read it